# "if" statement runs even though the conditions aren't met

Tags: c++

As you can see in the following, `int result` should get assigned value of 1 if only `int outcome` is 7 or 11. However, even though in the simulation I ran the `outcome` was 9, the if statement ran nontheless and assigns the value of `result` as 1.

The problem is, I'm not actually sure what's wrong because the other codes in the statement doesn't run, only result integer gets a value assigned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int bankroll=100;
    int bet=1;
    int die1[6]= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int die2[6]= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int outcome;
    int point;
    int result;
    bool pointroll=false;
    string resulttext;
    random_shuffle(&die1[0],&die1[6]);
    random_shuffle(&die2[0],&die2[6]);

    outcome = die1[0] + die2[0];
cout << "The Outcome is " << outcome << endl;
cout << "The Result is " << result << endl;
    if(outcome==7 || outcome==11)
    {
        resulttext="Win!";
        result=1;
        cout << "Am I running?" << endl;
    }
cout << "The Outcome is " << outcome << endl;
cout << "The Result is " << result << endl;

return 0;}
```

Here's the output:

```
The Outcome is 9
The Result is 0
The Outcome is 9
The Result is 1
```

Edit: I really can't believe how I overlooked such a simple thing. I didn't assign a starting value in the first place. Thanks everyone, question solved.

Comment: There's no need to put an edit that says the same thing as the answers. That's what the answers are for. You indicate that an answer is correct by accepting it.

Comment: Tip: Enable a decent level of compiler warnings (like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc and clang) and fix all of them. The compiler would have directly told you the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I actually placed the edit before checking the answers. But you are right.

Comment: If you figured out the answer yourself, you should post it as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the condition is true, result is set to 1, so much is true.  But in the other case, the content of result is undefined - so it can be anything, even allowing the compiler to modify it at will as part of an optimization.  You should either initialize result at its declaration, or add an else branch where you set it to the alternative value.

Comment: I am confused. He didn't use result in his if statement, so result has nothing to do with whether or not the if statement works.

Comment: @user13947194 - In the example run, `outcome` was 9, which means that the if-condition was false and the code within the then-block was not executed.  Therefore, in this case `result` has no defined value, not before the if statement, and also not after the if statement.  The behaviour of a program using an uninitialized variable is undefined - all kinds of behaviour are allowed: crashes, garbage output, whatever.  The value of `result` 'magically' changing is just another possibility.

Comment: but result is just an integer. The behaviour is undefined but only regarding what integer value is printed to std cout. The chances of a crash is zero. He has a function called random_shuffle, which seems to a user defined function. But since `int result` is a local variable, there is no way result has anything to do with random_shuffle. I think the problem lies in the random_shuffle function.

Answer (score 3):

You did not initialize result, so the content is *random garbage*.

If your IF runs, it overwrites it with 1; if it doesn't run, you print that *random garbage* (which happened to be 1).